# Little trouble with MySQL LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

I ask your help on a subject that I do not really master.

I have two tables:
tb_user (NIC_Handle, Pseudo)
tb_user_messages_recap (Auteur, Intervenant)

I have to retrieve the NIC_Handle of each 'Pseudo' that corresponds to either 'Auteur' or 'Intervenant'

Can you help me please ?

```
<?php try{
$MyPDO=$pdo->query("
SELECT 
tb_user_messages_recap.Auteur,
tb_user_messages_recap.Intervenant,
tb_user_messages_recap.Numero,
tb_user_messages_recap.Sujet,
tb_user_messages_recap.Creation,
tb_user_messages_recap.Edition,
tb_user_messages_recap.Etat,
tb_user.NIC_Handle,
tb_user.Pseudo

FROM tb_user_messages_recap

LEFT JOIN tb_user

ON tb_user_messages_recap.Auteur = tb_user.Pseudo

WHERE tb_user_messages_recap.Auteur='".$_SESSION_PSEUDO."' OR 
      tb_user_messages_recap.Intervenant='".$_SESSION_PSEUDO."' 

ORDER BY Edition DESC
");
    while($data=$MyPDO->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
?>

<?php echo $data["NIC_Handle"]." - ".$data["Auteur"]; ?>
<?php echo $data["NIC_Handle"]." - ".$data["Intervenant"]; ?>
<?php echo $data["NIC_Handle"]." - ".$data["Intervenant"]; ?>

<?php }}catch(PDOException $e){echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>".$e->getMessage()."</div>";} ?>
```

Thank you for your help,

Cordialy

Comment: So....what's wrong with your current query?  If you want us to help, do tell what's wrong with the current query?, what do you want to get?

Comment: The logic said that you need INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Change the join condition to:

```
ON tb_user_messages_recap.Auteur = tb_user.Pseudo OR
   tb_user_messages_recap.Intervenant= tb_user.Pseudo
```

But really why not:

```
SELECT NIC_Handle
FROM tb_user
WHERE Pseudo =$_SESSION_PSEUDO
```

I could be wrong. Question is a bit ambiguous.